# Any way to get old field name in one query on UPDATE with MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Say you were going to run an update query & update a field, however you wanted to also retrieve the prior value before the value is updated to the new value. Is there a way to do this in one query? Or do you have to run a SELECT before you run the UPDATE to get the value?

Comment: What do you mean by *retrieve the prior value*? Where do you want to save it in a query?

Comment: What's your need/use case for this?

Comment: Well what I am doing is if a new file is uploaded for this column I am wanting to get the filename of the old file & delete it... however I will need to do that before I update the filename with the new name obviously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to add a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to the table, during the processing of the trigger both the old and the new values of the affected column(s) would be available. See here for more... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html .

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to run SELECT query before you run the UPDATE one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you used [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html), you could do the select before the update and return the result once the update is done.